# Spinner BaseAdapter(android)

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

Sorry for my English. As research, I want to try to use the spinner with baseAdapter. But I do not know why I spinner does not output anything.

Its xml:
**student_list_questions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listsQuestions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**student_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/s_textQuestions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#7F8C8D"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/s_spinner_rating"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Class:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.student_list_questions);

Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
        SpinnerBaseAdapter adapter = new SpinnerBaseAdapter(this, new ArrayList<String>());
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

//then code 
}
```

And this spinner adapter:

```
public class SpinnerBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> numberList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SpinnerBaseAdapter(Context context, Object results) {
        numberList = (List<String>) results;
        numberList.add("1");
        numberList.add("2");
        numberList.add("3");
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return numberList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.spinnerValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.s_spinner_rating);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.spinnerValue.setText(numberList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView spinnerValue;
    }


}
```

Comment: `But I do not know why I spinner does not output anything.` because Spinner is created dynamically but not added in current activity layout ether add Spinner in xml or use addView to add Spinner dynamically in root view

Comment: You need to set adapter to listview and you are creating new spinner, it is not from your layout